# building dogecoin wallet from git on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, json

I'm trying to build the dogecoin wallet from the git source on arch linux.

I've installed all of the dependencies that the README listed as required but I continuously get this error:

```
obj/bitcoinrpc.o:/home/delta9/dogecoin/src/json/json_spirit_value.h:346: more undefined   references to `json_spirit::Value_type_name' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.unix:195: recipe for target 'dogecoind' failed
make: *** [dogecoind] Error 1
```

I'm sure I'm still missing a required json library but I am not sure which one. I've installed the jsoncpp library from pacman and still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [`doc/readme-qt.rst`](http://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-qt/blob/master/doc/readme-qt.rst) instead to compile the Qt client and that one will work. Just did so on Debian.

Comment: Can you link to that one, or describe the steps here, please?

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. On archlinux I ran qmake-qt4 then make and it was succesful

Comment: @slhck: It's in the same source package, e.g. see here: https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-qt/blob/master/doc/readme-qt.rst